# File synchronize completes with no data

Tags: file-manager, sync, ftp

I'm working with the basic file upload preferences from inside of the control panel. I'm uploading videos and audio files for a podcast. Some are larger HD files (1gb) some are small mp3s (15mb). The folder permissions are all set correctly. The paths are all set correctly. And the upload directories have been working using the synchronize button previously.

Ok, so I uploaded files via FTP to the correct folder.
I go into file upload preferences and click synchronize
I click submit and wait, and wait, and wait, and wait.
It says that it successfully completed processing 60 files in the folder.

It lies . . . some files are missing. They are there in FTP but not available to EE. I need help. If I purchased ChannelFiles would that solve my problem?

Comment: What kind of files are missing? By default, EE only allows certain kinds of files (defined in **/system/expressonengine/config/mimes.php**).

Comment: Are there special characters on the names of these files?